# Using COALESCE in oracle and getting ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, database, oracle, left-join

I am trying to use COALESCE function in query but it throws an error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis but the same query is running well in mysql i dont know how to write same query in orcale please help me out from this error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sut.SERVICE_USER_TYPE , COUNT(er.ENFORCMENT_ID)
, SUM(er.FINE_AMOUNT),
COALESCE(er.CHECK_DATE>=('12-JAN-15'), er.CHECK_DATE<=('12-JAN-15''11.59.59.465000000 PM'))
from SERVICE_USER_TYPE sut 
LEFT JOIN SERVICE_USERS su  
ON su.SERVICE_USER_TYPE_ID = sut.SERVICE_USER_TYPE_ID 
LEFT JOIN ENFORCEMENT_REPORT er ON su.SERVICE_USER_ID = er.SERVICE_USER_ID 

group by sut.SERVICE_USER_TYPE  ;
```

and the error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 23
```

please help me out..

Comment: You can't use a condition like `er.CHECK_DATE>=('12-JAN-15')` in the `coalesce()` function. You also shouldn't use string literals like that to compare against dates. Use a proper date literal either using an ISO literal `DATE '....'` or Oracle's `to_date()` function.

Comment: then how can I use condition ? I am new in oracle

Comment: What are you trying to do with that expression? It doesn't make sense. It essentially says "*if the result of the condition a >= b is null then use the result of the condition a <= c*". The result of a condition is always `true` or `false` (unless the column is `null`). So the outcome of that `coalesce()` would be a boolean value. But Oracle does not have a boolean data type. And neither does MySQL - it simply silently converts any "boolean" expression to 0 or 1. So what exactly you are trying to solve with that expression? (Btw: the parentheses around the values are totally useless).

Comment: Just a comment, when GROUP BY is involved the result is implicitly distinct, so you can remove DISTINCT.

Comment: believe me the same query is running well in mysql I want to display both null and not null values

Answer (score 0):

You say this works in MySQL. Well, the COALESCE expression results in 0, 1 or NULL per record. Then you aggregate your rows, but there is no aggregate on your COALESCE expression. This gives you a random 0, 1 or NULL per SERVICE_USER_TYPE.

The COALESCE expression

```
COALESCE(er.CHECK_DATE>=('12-JAN-15'), er.CHECK_DATE<=('12-JAN-15''11.59.59.465000000 PM'))
```

does the following in MySQL (only obfuscated):

```
CASE 
  WHEN er.CHECK_DATE IS NULL THEN NULL
  WHEN er.CHECK_DATE >= '12-JAN-15' THEN 1
  WHEN er.CHECK_DATE <  '12-JAN-15' THEN 0
END
```

or, with NULL being the default, shortly

```
CASE 
  WHEN er.CHECK_DATE >= '12-JAN-15' THEN 1
  WHEN er.CHECK_DATE <  '12-JAN-15' THEN 0
END
```

You can do the same in Oracle and any other DBMS, but think about what aggregate you want to see. (If you expect it to be the same within all records for a SERVICE_USER_TYPE, use MIN or MAX or AVG, whichever you like best.)

For instance:

```
MIN
(
  CASE 
    WHEN er.CHECK_DATE >= DATE'2015-01-12' THEN 1 
    WHEN er.CHECK_DATE <  DATE'2015-01-12' THEN 0 
  END
)
```